# Checkboxes values in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

Whats the problem with below code.Error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        foreach($_POST['team[]'] as $value)
        {
        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO team('team') VALUES ('$value')");
        }
        if($insert)
        {
        echo "dONE";
        }
        }
<form method="post" action="check.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="team[]" value="AG"> Argentina
<input type="checkbox" name="team[]" value="GE"> Germany
<input type="checkbox" name="team[]" value="BR"> Brazil
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should use `foreach($_POST['team'] as $value)`

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
foreach($_POST['team'] as $value)
```

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried? Just test it on my localhost and it works.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: can you give share the whole code,with db connection.i want to test in my localhost also.Kindly

Comment: Well, my answer solve the error you describe in your question. But it seems that you have others errors now. You have 2 options: update this question with more information about new errors (and the code that provide these errors) or post a new question with new errors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't refer to `team[]`. Instead use

```
if (isset($_POST['team'])) {
    foreach($_POST['team'] as $value) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @FAIQNASEEM is $_POST['team'] set?

Comment: @FAIQNASEEM do a `var_dump()` on $_POST and see what it contains when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

When you will receive from the $_POST the variable team, it will be an array of every checkbox.

So instead of using `team[]` you should use

```
foreach($_POST['team'] as $value)
```

Also, you should be aware that if no checkbox were checked, the key team will not exist, so make sure before your foreach to do a `if (isset($_POST['team']))`

also you are overwriting insert at every time you loop.

you may want to do something like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['team']))
    {
        $insert = true;

        foreach($_POST['team'] as $value)
        {
            // we add security with mysql_real_escape_string
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO team('team') VALUES ('$value')");

            if (!$result)
            {
                $insert = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if($insert)
        {
            echo "dONE";
        }
    }
}
```

you may want to check [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to add secrurity to your code

Comment: @FAIQNASEEM Depending of what data you want to store into your database, yes this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `name=something[]` on an input, php will create the array for you so you just need to do

`foreach($_POST['team'] as $value)`

Also something like `name=team[member][]` could be iterated through in php like so

`foreach($_POST['team']['member'] as $value)`

So it makes grouping inputs and well as processing multiple dynamic inputs very easy

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$teams = $_POST['team'];
$submitted = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submitted) && is_array($teams)) {

     foreach($teams as $team) {
          /* Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement */ 
          $team = mysql_real_escape_string($team)
          $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO team('team') VALUES ('$team')");
     }

     if($insert) {
          echo "dONE";
    }
} else {
    echo "Either Form Not Submitted or Teams is Not Array";
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: If you are still getting "Invalid argument supplied foreach()", try my revised answer.

Comment: Either Form Not Submitted or Teams is Not Array,this is printed on page

Comment: right before the if statement, try print_r($_POST['team']) does that show you the values you checked?